# Не работает маленький код с if

Tags: javascript

```
var login = prompt('Введите логин !');
    if (login == 'Admin' || 'User'){
    var password = prompt('Введите пароль !');
        if (password == '12345'){
            alert("Добро пожаловать");
        }
        else if (password == null){
            alert("Вы уже уходите?");
        }
        else{
            alert("Go away");
        }
    }
    else{
        alert("Who are you?");
    }
```

Почему  в поле для ввода логина когда ввожу любые циферки и буквы оно переходит на поле для ввода пароля а не выводит "Go away".Если я убираю (|| 'User') то все работает как надо.Но мне надо что бы было так: Если логин "Admin" или "User" то выводит поле для ввода пароля.Если что-то другое то выводит "Go away"

Comment: Когда на вопросы дают верный ответ, его надо принимать нажатием на галочку слева от него. Если не ошибаюсь, это можно сделать через 15 минут после вопроса.

Comment: Ответ уже дали, стоит только пояснить, что условие `login == 'Admin' || 'User'` эквивалентно условию `(login == 'Admin') || 'User'`, что эквивалентно `(login == 'Admin') || true`, что эквивалентно `(true || false) || true`, что эквивалентно `true`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Вместо

```
if (login == 'Admin' || 'User'){
```

надо

```
if (login == 'Admin' || login == 'User') {
```

```js
var login = prompt('Введите логин !');
if (login == 'Admin' || login == 'User') {
  var password = prompt('Введите пароль !');
  if (password == '12345') {
    alert("Добро пожаловать");
  } else if (password == null) {
    alert("Вы уже уходите?");
  } else {
    alert("Go away");
  }
} else {
  alert("Who are you?");
}
```